# Using 2d Indexes, in aggregate with $geoNear

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, geolocation, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use geoNear with aggregate but i get this error massage:

```
errmsg: "'near' field must be point"
```

Because my location field is [Number]:

```
var locationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name            : String,
addressText     : String,
location    : [Number] // [<longitude>, <latitude>] 
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema );
```

And i trying to aggregate like this:

```
Location.aggregate([
            {$geoNear: {
                near: {type : "Point", "location": [ 48.2, 16.3 ]},
                limit: 1000000,
                distanceField: "dist.calculated",
                includeLocs: "true",
                maxDistance: 10
            }}
        ])
        .exec()
```

I know that i have to add my location `type:"Point"` but it is unfortunately too late. Can i fix this problem with other way?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "location" in the aggregate with "coordinates".